# Difference between Java Swing application & Netbeans platform Swing

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I want to develop a simple desktop application that connects to the Java DB , using Java Swing for the interface design.
  I am new to Swing so I tried some tutorials on the net and came across 
 the Netbeans platform Swing components.

1. What is
   the difference between the Java Swing architecture and the Netbeans Swing components?
2. Which one will be appropriate for developing interfaces 
   for desktop applications in Java?

Answer (score 4):

From [The NetBeans Platform](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/):

> The NetBeans Platform is a generic framework for Swing applications. It provides the "plumbing" that, before, every developer had to write themselves—saving state, connecting actions to menu items, toolbar items and keyboard shortcuts; window management, and so on.

It is an API built with Swing, that is supposed to provide some extra 'built-in' functionality.  Since you need to know Swing to be able to use it.  I suggest you concentrate on Swing for now.

Comment: I concur. Though I (think I) like the NetBeans Platform, for starters it might derail your efforts.

Comment: thanks guys think will keep with the swing and later move to the NetBeans Platform

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it will be better to move on Intellij Idea from Jet Brains. It’s much more better than NetBeans IDE. Of course, it’s only my opinion.

Comment: The NetBeans Platform is not the same thing as the NetBeans IDE.